# Python Identify File Path to Module

Tags: python, module, jython-2.7, sys.path

The regular `os.path.dirname(__file__)` doesn't work in a special setting I'm currently in. I hope this is not having an influence, but it's Jython 2.7.

```
text_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
NameError: global name '__file__' is not defined
```

If I call `os.path.dirname(__file__)` from inside a function it works just fine.

**Version 1 (works)**

bar.py

```
import os
def bar():
  location = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  return location
```

**Version 2 (doesn't work, see above NameError)**

extension.py

```
import os
from some_tool import Extensions
class extended(Extensions):
  def foo():
    location = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Any idea to why? Is it related to Jython? Or because it is inside a `class`? Or because it is inherting something?

**Current Workaround**

extension.py

```
import bar
from some_tool import Extensions
class extended(Extensions):
    def foo():
        location = bar.bar()
```

Comment: aren't quotes characters in `__file__` unnecessary?

Comment: @pt12lol They're not unnecessary, they're wrong.

Comment: I checked both options, and both seems to work on my local.

Comment: 'both' I mean with and without quotes. None says about `/opt/process`.

Comment: @phant0m, sorry about that typo. I fixed that. Also updated the question.

Comment: Have you tried importing like `from . import foo.bar` ini extension.py?

Comment: in that version it works fine, it's in the one that is more straight forward, where it doesn't work. I wonder if it is a problem, because it is inside a `class`?!?

Comment: I would assume that it has to do with how python loads modules. When you are not calling your script from /opt/process, then /opt/process/foo/bar.py is not in your path, neither is /opt/proces, so `import foo.bar` must fail. If you import like `from . import foo.bar`, you are telling the python interpreter to look at a path relative to the scripts location.

Comment: @pt12lol `'__file__'` is just a regular string, you will get the same result if you try `'thisfiledoesnotexist'`. `__file__` without the quotes however is a "magic" variable which Python will set to the filename of the current module.

Comment: apparently the question was really badly phrased. I did re-write it for clarification purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer below is for [revision 1 of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40524271/1)**

It worked for me:

```
 $ pwd
/tmp
 $ cat test.py
import os; print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
 $ python test.py
/tmp
```

`'__file__'` works for me as well.

Comment: How does that relate to the question? It was essentially about imports, althought the title might be missleading.

Comment: I see - and now it has changed again - my excuses.

Comment: @Isaac (and anyone who visit this question or is just interested in): I asked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286803/change-to-question-invalidates-my-answer-what-to-do/286809) what to do in situation like this one and got [a great answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286809/343874).